# Do I need to repeatedly run the same merge command after resolving reported merge conflict?

Tags: git

After resolving merge conflict and `git add` and `git commit` the resolved result,
if I run the same `git merge` command again, will there still be merge conflict? I guess no, because `git add` and `git commit` makes the current branch ahead of the merged branch, so nothing to merge again.

But I heard that I need to repeat running the same `git merge` command and resolving merge conflict and add and commit, till the same `git merge` command doesn't report conflict. 
Is that really true? Or did I misheard and thus misunderstand what I heard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to merge and there are merge conflicts, the current attempt to merge will be **discarded**. You will not have actually merged your changes, and you will be **forced** to do so before you are able to merge.

If you have indeed successfully resolved your conflicts and attempt the merge again, there will almost certainly be no merge conflicts the second time around. The only possible way you would receive merge conflicts on the second attempt to merge would be if another develop had successfully committed a conflicting file during the time you were resolving your original conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably faster to try than asking the question ;) As you can see if, you try to merge again then git will tell you that everything is up to date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing the merge once is sufficient. If you've added and committed the result, then you don't need to do it again. Attempting to merge that branch again won't have any effect, since it will already be merged.

As a note, if you have `git rerere` enabled (with the `rerere.enabled` option), any merge conflict that's been seen before will be repeated with the last resolution you committed. That may be the situation that had been mentioned to you.